# Asus x451ca ram is 8GB and is core i3

Tags: windows, windows-10

Please am using Asus x451ca and I want to reset my bios battery but I can't I have remove the cmos battery for 15 minutes and plug it back still asking for the password please can help me that please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please use punctuation and write out separate sentences make your question more clear.